# How to add many attribute elements in same element?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add many elements with some attributes in same element. Here is my code,

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("ABC");
doc.AppendChild(root);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    XmlElement anotherid;
    XmlElement id;
    id = doc.CreateElement("DEF");
    anotherid = doc.CreateElement("GEH");
    anotherid.SetAttribute("Name", "");
    anotherid.SetAttribute("Button", "");
    root.AppendChild(id);
    id.AppendChild(anotherid);

}
doc.Save(@"C:\dummyxml.xml");
```

It gives output like this following:

```
<ABC>
  <DEF>
    <GEH Name="" Button="" />
  </DEF>
  <DEF>
    <GEH Name="" Button="" />
  </DEF>
  <DEF>
    <GEH Name="" Button="" />
  </DEF>
</ABC>
```

But I want output like

```
   <ABC>
      <DEF>
        <GEH Name="" Button="" />
        <GEH Name="" Button=""/>
        <GEH Name="" Button=""/>
      </DEF>
    </ABC>
```

please don't neglect for loop. I want output with for loop only. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically the `for` loop should *only* contain the creation of the `GEH` element. You can move the creation of the `DEF` element outside the loop...

However, I'd also strongly recommend using LINQ to XML rather than the old XmlDocument API... it's much simpler. In this case, the code would look like this:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("ABC",
        new XElement("DEF",
            Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
                      .Select(ignored => new XElement("GEH",
                           new XAttribute("Name", ""),
                           new XAttribute("Button", "")
                      )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration of the `DEF` element one level upwards.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("ABC");
doc.AppendChild(root);
XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("DEF");

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    XmlElement anotherid;
    anotherid = doc.CreateElement("GEH");
    anotherid.SetAttribute("Name", "");
    anotherid.SetAttribute("Button", "");
    root.AppendChild(id);
    id.AppendChild(anotherid);

}
doc.Save("dummyxml.xml");
```

produces

```
<ABC>
  <DEF>
    <GEH Name="" Button="" />
    <GEH Name="" Button="" />
    <GEH Name="" Button="" />
  </DEF>
</ABC>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just moved code outside the for loop

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("ABC");
            doc.AppendChild(root);

            XmlElement anotherid;
            XmlElement id;
            id = doc.CreateElement("DEF");

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                anotherid = doc.CreateElement("GEH");
                anotherid.SetAttribute("Name", "");
                anotherid.SetAttribute("Button", "");
                root.AppendChild(id);
                id.AppendChild(anotherid);

            }
            doc.Save(@"C:\dummyxml.xml");​
```